# Transaction in DynamoDb returns an error on put method

Tags: php, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I would like to make a put operation within a transaction in a php project with dynamodb so with aws sdk. I have tried this:

```
$data =  [
            'id' => ['S' => $uuid->toString()],
            'post_id' => ['N' => '1'],
            'occurred_at' => ['S' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
        ];


$this->client->transactWriteItems([
                'TransactItems' => [
                    [
                        'Put' => [
                            'TableName' => $this->table,
                            'Item' => $data
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
```

It returns me this error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST http://localhost:8000` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"__type":"com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#UnknownOperationException","message":"An unknown operation was requested."}
```

If I make a simple putItem it works fine.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Transactions were just announced, are they supported in your SDK and your region?

Comment: I hope yes, it's not easy to understand if are supported

Comment: What does the payload of your request look like once it’s built?